# How to create DeckGL custom data source?

Tags: javascript, maps, deck.gl

I wanna use this DeckGL layer in my project.
https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=001

But I want to use custom data source. Current data source looks like this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/website/sf-bike-parking.json

```
const layer = new HexagonLayer({
  id: 'HexagonLayer',
  data: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/website/sf-bike-parking.json',
```

I really don't know how to create COORDINATES so there would be exact GPS values matching with hexagons size.
Does anyone know how to create that custom JSON file?

Thanks.